# Encoding.GetEncoding ucs 2 little endian

Tags: c#

**I'm trying to find a string or (not so ideally) int representation of `UCS-2 little endian` to input into `Encoding.GetEncoding()`**.

I am looking for this information because I'm using `StreamReader` to read a content of a file and I want to use `Encoding.GetEncoding` to construct it.

The reason for that is I'm reading several different files with variable encodings and I need to be able to specify in configuration which encoding to use for what file.

Comment: Have you tried "utf-16" as listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8? I realize UCS-2 and UTF-16 aren't identical, but I strongly suspect it will work for you.

Comment: Encoding works on byte[] and is used to read the byte[] into a string.  You cannot use Encoding on a string.  So use :  Array.Find().

Comment: @jdweng I'm a little confused by your comment; it is entirely normal and usual to use `Encoding` with `StreamStreader`; not sure where `Array.Find` came from here...

Comment: The op want to determine what encoding to use ("which encoding to use for what file").  So the OP need to search the byte[] before encoding is applied.

Comment: my understanding is that UTF-16 should indeed be able to read input that is UCS-2 - in that it is *essentially* backwards compatible over the code-points that UCS-2 can handle, so: for **reading**, `Encoding.Unicode` should work fine here? or it at least worth a try. In terms of use with `GetEncoding`: this is code-page `1200` (or `1201` for big-endian) - or by name: `"Unicode"` (or `"Unicode (Big-Endian)"`)

Comment: @jdweng I don't see *anything* about OP trying to *infer* the encoding here

Comment: @jdweng True, I'm not trying to infer the encoding, since I read it from configuration. although it is an interesting idea which I will spend some time thinking about. Thank you for your advice. :)

Comment: MarcGravell and jon-skeet are both most probably right, since I'm only reading the file. Whoever of you will write an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @jdweng: The OP says they need to be able to *specify in configuration* which encoding to use for what file. That's not the same as determining it from the file. That's why they mention `Encoding.GetEncoding`, which allows you to retrieve an encoding by name or number,

Comment: Many file have header information.  It this case the encoding may be in the header.  So the OP needs to search the bytes to determine the encoding before applying the encoding.

Comment: @jdweng hey, we should find an unused but valid code-point, maybe U+FEFF, and write it at the start of the file in the chosen encoding - then readers could check the first few bytes and see whether they can construct that code-point via any encoding, and: voila! now what could we call such a thing... it is like a mark that indicates the order of the bytes...

Comment: I was just answering the OP question not knowing the details of the file.  So I didn't propose any solutions or issues.

Comment: @jdweng: But you *did* propose a solution - you proposed "searching the bytes to determine the encoding before applying the encoding". But that's not a solution to the question that the OP asked. They've indicated that they already have a way of keeping track of the encoding of each file in a separate configuration file. There's no indication in this question that they need to *detect* the encoding at all. They just want to know the name to use in that configuration file so that `Encoding.GetEncoding` will return a UCS-2 encoding - and that's what Marc's answer gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCS-2 can be considered a subset of UTF-16, and thus any UTF-16 capable decoder should *also* be able to handle UCS-2; the difference is that UCS-2 doesn't cover the *entire range* of unicode, and thus there are some *additional* values that can be expressed in UTF-16 but *not* in UCS-2. We just shouldn't expect to *see* those values here, if the file was written by an encoder that only knows UCS-2.

This is pretty much the same as saying that you can use a UTF-8 decoder to read data that was written in pure ASCII (where by "pure" here, I mean 7-bit ASCII, not the extended code-pages that use the 8th bit).

As such, any of:

```cs
Encoding direct = Encoding.Unicode;
Encoding byCode = Encoding.GetEncoding(1200);
Encoding byName = Encoding.GetEncoding("Unicode");
```

should work fine here.